# Using a Cron Job to Open every page on a site based on it's sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, apache, cron

I want to ensure my cache on my webpage remains fresh and doesn't get purged and we don't get 524 errors, which we have been seeing regularly

We use the following in the Crontab config.

```
*/15 * * * * wget -O – https://www.mysite; wget -O – https://www.mysite/contact
```

However this is getting very cumbersome now the site has grown.  Can someone help me create a way to get the webpages based around my site map itself on the apache server? I have a sitemap-index.xml that then lists 6 other smaller sitemaps.  Each of those has been generated by the Yoast plugin.

Is this an efficient way to make sure my W3 cache is working correctly with Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to create a shell script to run your wget commands instead of having them all in your crontab like this. Just create refresh_cache.sh, make it executable, and set it up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O – https://www.mysite
wget -O – https://www.mysite/contact
```

With one command per line as shown.

Then in your crontab just put the path to the script:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/refresh_cache.sh
```

This would make it less cumbersome to manage.

To automate it you could write a script to parse your XML files and then fetch the URLs but you would need to post a sample of them for more info on that, and you would need to identify which scripting language you want to use.

Sorting out your caching so this isn't necessary is a different question. Look in your log files to see what the error is when a 524 is generated.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense.  As a first step I can download and parse on my own computer the XML and then do a line by line script file quite quickly! As for the 524 i'm using Apache2 and Wordpress, where would I find the log files?

Comment: Great, yes, that's the idea and should be much easier for you. Regarding your caching setup, really that's a separate question, and a completely different one, and needs more information providing about your setup to answer properly. So I suggest you start a different question about that, to encourage others to answer and get it under the correct tags for that to happen. If you're happy with my answer you could perhaps accept it. Thanks.